# variable with function name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way to concatenate loop with function name
like i have form  which have append button to add 5 more location div via jquery append function , 5 times loop over location div .location div have state city and zip code code select option which will be call by ajax in jquery here is my code.room is loop name.

```
<select data-live-search="true" class="form-control " name="sAState'+room+'" id="sAState'+room+'" onChange="AddLoadCity+room();">
       <option value="1">state1</option>
       <option value="2">state2</option>
       </select>
     <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-10 col-xs-12" id="AddCityDiv'+room+'" ><select data-live-search="true" class="form-control " name="sCity" id="sCity'+room'" onChange="LoadZipCode'+room+'();"> 
<option value="1">city1</option>
 <option value="2">city2</option></select></div>

        for(i=0;i;i<5;i++)
        {
          function AddLoadCity+i()
            {
            alert($('#sAState'+i+').val()); 
            }
          function AddLoadZip+i()
            {
            alert($('#sCity'+i').val()); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: punctuation saves lives

Comment: Multiple functions are not necessary. Can you include full `html` and `javascript` at Question?

Comment: Just Please tell me who can call function name dynamically function Loadcity'+loop+'(){...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you totally want to create multible functions with dynamic names. But if you really wanted to, you would do it maybe like this:

```
var functions = [];
for(i=0;i;i<5;i++)
    {
      functions['AddLoadCity'+i] = function()
        {
        alert($('#sAState'+i).val()); 
        }
      functions['AddLoadZip'+i] = function()
        {
        alert($('#sCity'+i).val()); }
        }
    }
```

Then you could call them like

```
functions.AddLoadZip1()
```

Edit:

Also they is a mistake in

```
$('#sAState'+i+').val()
```

namely the +' is a syntax error.

Comment: thanks but it really call by dynamic because . in bootstrap addmore.js have loop over append Location div .Location div have state city and zip so i want to get value where user click on location div .is div 1 div 2 .....? according to get city value and zip value .but if you have more idea you can share .thanks